# how to print the result of my child params of the firebase on the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

**how to print the result of my child params of the firebase on the screen?**

error:  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {datetime, extras, params}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.app = firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config);
    this.database = this.app.database().ref().child('users');
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.database.once("value", snapshot => {
   snapshot.forEach(data => {
    data.forEach(result => {
      this.setState({users: result.val()})
    });
   })
 });
}

render() {
   return(
     <BrowserRouter>
       <div className="App">
         <Navbar/>
         <Switch>
          <Route exact="exact" path='/' component={CampaingListClients}/>
         </Switch>
        <p>{this.state.users}</p>
      </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
 }
}
```

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {datetime, extras, params}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

My firebase structure here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E5ce.png)

Error Description HERE: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqFrP.png)

Comment: What do you get when you do console.log(this.state.users) in render?

Comment: Both the error message and the JSON are text. Don't post screenshots of textual content please. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make them look good. You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
render() {
  const { users } = this.state;
  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact="exact" path='/' component={CampaingListClients}/>
      </Switch>
      <p>
        {users.map(user => {
          <span key={user.name}>
            <span>{user.name}</span>
            <span>{user.email}</span>
          </span>
        })}
      </p>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: ./src/App.js
  Line 42:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: <Switch>
            <Route exact="exact" path='/' component={CampaingListClients}/>
         </Switch>
         <p>{this.state.users}</p>

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you want to render?